Performance of unbiased MMSE vs. biased MMSE
Did somebody ever read the paper Yen, R.Y., 2009. Unbiased MMSE vs. biased MMSE equalizers. Journal of Applied Science and Engineering, 12(1), pp.45-56?
The biased MMSE is shown to have lower MSE than the unbiased MMSE, which I believe means the fomer estimate is closer to the real symbol than the latter. But surprisingly the former has worse SEP (symbol error probability) than the latter. What is the logic behind this phenomenon?

it feels like you are asking about the Cramér-Rao Lower Bound without realizing? Haven't read the paper, as the server your link points doesn't allow me to connect, but I'd be surprised if it didn't mention the CRLB. It applies to unbiased estimators, so a biased estimator might be better in estimation variance than an unbiases estimator; but it's no big surprise that something that has an estimation bias has worse performance at estimating something zero-mean as symbols from a symmetrical constellation than an unbiased estimator.

I likewise am unable to access the paper, but in estimation theory (and statistical signal processing in general) there is a well known bias-variance tradeoff. Typically, introducing small bias can reduce your variance, sometimes significantly so. Since $MSE = var + bias^{2}$, you can often achieve better MSE with biased estimators. Like Marcus implied in his comment, introducing too large of a bias, at the potential of a drastic reduction in variance, could lead to the equalizer favoring a certain symbol too often.

I've edited the link. It is OK now. Look at the MMSE criteria. Doesn't lower MSE mean the estimate is closer to the true transmitted symbol?

It's already been shown in this paper for symbol detection unbiased MMSE is better than biased MMSE for SEP. Do you expect the former is also better for soft decision and channel decoding case? And do you expect unbiased MMSE to be better for other tasks, like channel estimation?

I did some experiment for unbiased channel estimation and found no gain. I'm even more confused now.

@Baddioes By the way, where can I find a reference for the decomposition into bias and variance you mentioned. What I found on the web seems to treat the parameter as deterministic.
